# Access correct XML Nodes with XMLParser

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I cant access the nodes of the XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>cnt_id</key>
        <string>lovenyc</string>
        <key>user</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>emps_cnpj</key>
        <string>11379404000154</string>
        <key>depto_id</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>id_device</key>
        <string>7543AF5F-495D-4739-BB83-56BF08CE7DF0</string>
        <key>data_acesso</key>
        <string>2013-01-04 12:48:21</string>
        <key>id_usuario</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>user_fav</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>user_like</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>user_lat</key>
        <string></string>
      </dict>
    </array>
 </plist>
```

The objective-c Code :

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)
namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *) qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    _xmlObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"Attribute %@",[attributeDict allKeys]);
    NSLog(@"Attribute Values %@",[attributeDict allValues]);
}
```

The log always gave me null values, and I can't access the `<string>` value for example, any advices?
Thanks

Comment: The xml looks like a plist with an array so why don't you use NSArray's arrayWithContentsOfFile to load it automatically instead of parsing manually?

Comment: @AnnaKarenina Never tried this, can you show some example please?Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing property lists is a trivial, one-line task using Foundation objects:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"PropList.plist"];
```

More info in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-CBHBIGBI).

(Note that you have to use the proper class - if the root object of the property list is `<dict>`, then you should use `+ [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:]` instead.)